# Why does the bounty on my answer not show up in the "bounty" tab?

Tags: bug, bounty, reputation-history

One of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816904/5740382) was awarded a 50 reputation bounty. [The bounty tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740382/kiran-shahi?tab=bounties&sort=earned) in my profile though doesn't show any earned bounties. I think this might a be bug and that there should not be a bounty on my answer.

[image: Bounty earned]

[image: 0 bounty earned on profile]

Comment: Both [the question revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45816480/revisions) and [your reputation tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ3HS.png) show that you were awarded that bounty on March 26. If there's a bug, it looks like it's with the earned bounties tab.

Comment: Yes it might be. Thank you for your comment. :)

Comment: Oddly, it doesn't show on the awarding user's offered bounties page either: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5674863/sumit-bhattarai?tab=bounties&sort=offered

Comment: @MikeM. noticed just now

Comment: @NickA might be, Thank you for your comment. :)

Comment: It does show up in your [reputation tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfaxu.png) for that date..So it must be added

Comment: Strangely enough the bountystart events are there in the Votes table but not the the bountyend: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855919

Comment: ha ha @rene there might be some thing wrong on sql.

Comment: Given that the person who awarded the bounty and the person who asked the question have the same name this is probably a sock puppet account. Both your reputation tabs show voting irregularities. This may be due to an account being deleted then undeleted again.

Comment: @user2285236 that sounds likely according to the rep [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4PCO.png) the offering account did lose 50 rep for bounty and later there was a reversal. So the question remains why the post is showing the bounty.

Comment: @SurajRao I have mention in question "I think there should not be bounty on my answer." :) any way thank you for your comment.

Comment: @user2285236 I don't know whether that was puppet account or not but that was not my account. I was just answering that question. If the bounty was roll backed then the bounty must be removed. I think it was bug. Any way thank you for your comment.

Comment: Are you two classmates? Workmates? Neighbours?

Comment: @coldspeed no we are not

Comment: Because the bounty was reverted when a CM cleared the votes in a voting ring. The OP was contacted about that by a moderator at the time. That a bounty label hangs around is a known bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok thank you for your comment. :)

Comment: Probably needs to be an answer :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually I was just posting about bug. I have mention in question "I think there should not be bounty on my answer. ";

Comment: @KiranShahi: What I mean is that Martijn's explanation would be an answer to your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh IC lol

Comment: That ~500 drop in your rep looks suspicious. How many bounties did you lose?

Answer (score 6):

To cite [the answering comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368562/why-does-the-bounty-on-my-answer-not-show-up-in-the-bounty-tab#comment594417_368562) by [Martijn Pieters♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters):

> Because the bounty was reverted when a CM cleared the votes in a voting ring. The OP was contacted about that by a moderator at the time. That a bounty label hangs around is a known bug.

So don't do voting fraud, it will be detected, and it is a known bug that the bounty "sticker" hangs around on the answer after account deletion due to voting fraud. So the bug is indeed in the label on the answer, and not on the bounty tab itself, as the bounty has been removed by a Community Moderator and should be gone entirely, in reputation, the bounty-tab and the label itself.
I doubt that fixing this bug is too much of a priority though, since catching the fraud takes precedence.

Comment: Is it fair to accuse the OP of taking part in voting fraud? I didn't see any evidence of that unless the mods know something.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I'm not accusing the OP; I'm just saying that voting fraud will be detected and reverted, which a moderator stated is the root cause of the problem at hand. Whether the OP knowingly and willingy participated in the voting fraud is not for me to say, but Martijn saying that the OP at hand was contacted for exactly that, is enough for me to say "don't do voting fraud"

Comment: It sort of comes off as an accusal when your first sentence is "don't do voting fraud". And you are directly answering the OP's question.

Comment: Also, the OP that was contacted by Martijn is not the OP of this question.

Comment: Two users that live 197 kilometers apart in Nepal does tend to inspire one to recommend "don't do it".  As does the subsequent vote reversal.  If it quacks like a duck then it is usually a duck.